# Actionscript3 E4X XML and CSS: Do I really have to use CDATA?

Tags: actionscript-3, e4x, cdata

When working with CSS inside of XML such as

```
<span class="IwuvAS3"></span>
```

when parsed in flash, if I don't use CDATA like the following:

```
<![CDATA[<span class="IwuvAS3"></span>]]>
```

then the parsed data drops down a line for every "<" character it sees.

When parsing the data into a single-line text field, nothing was shown because it was actually down a line.  Soon as I wrap it inside of `CDATA` it works great.  I have played with `prettyIndent`, and as I understand `ignoreWhite` is true by default.

Is there a way to parse the data without the use of `CDATA` and keep the implied line breaks out?

**EDIT 1 (10/10/08)**:  Thank you, but I am actually looking for a Function or Method.  Escaping each is much more cumbersome than using CDATA.  The only reason I don't want to use CDATA is that I was taught to stay clear of it.  If ActionScript has a method associated to E4X XML handling that will remove the requirement to wrap my XML in CDATA, I would love to know about it.

**EDIT 1 (10/15/08)**:  Thanks Philippe!  I never would have thought that HTML formatting in Flash is treated as whitespace.  The answer was

```
textField.condenseWhite = true;
```

<3AS3

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Set the TextField's **condenseWhite** property to true - so only < br/> tags will generate linebreaks.

Comment: Thanks alot, I never would have thought flash would treat the <span class=""> stuff as white space.  This worked perfectly!  CDATA IS EVIL!

Comment: span itself doesn't add whitespace, but Flash automatically reformats XML when it is converted to text. So XML nodes and text elements get indented - additional whitespace comes from this indentation.

Answer (score 0):

You could escape the "<" characters (and &, ", >, ', among others) as entities instead.